# Dojo get element type

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I would like to use javascript to get a dijit element type. e.g. if the item is a textbox, combobox, filteringselect and so on. Here is what i have tried and it resulted in undefined being returned.

**HTML**

```
<s:textfield type="text" id="name" required="true" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" />

<s:select id="gender" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var genderType = dijit.byId('gender').attr('data-dojo-type');

var name= dijit.byId('name').attr('data-dojo-type');

console.log(genderType);
console.log(name);
```

**Results**

```
undefined
undefined
```

Comment: Could you provide jsfiddle?

Comment: Try this way : `var yourWidgetType = dojo.filter(dijit.registry._hash, function(widget) {
  return widget.declaredClass;
})`

Comment: @user3241019 its not returning any results

Comment: Do you get any result if trying to access your widget with its ID ? [Here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/registry.html) is the Dojo doc to give you an example through the dijit registry (v1.9)

Comment: @user3241019 i have tried dijit.registry.byId('widgetName') and dijit.byId('widgetName') and still no results

Comment: @user3241019 Is it possible for me to access the role attribute ? this would make what i am trying to achieve simpler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to get them is indeed by using the `declaredClass` property, however, I'm not sure if it's a good thing to rely on it, simply because it's mostly undocumented.

In your case it would be:

```
require([ "dojo/ready", "dijit/registry" ], function(ready, registry) {
    ready(function() {
        console.log(registry.byId("gender").get("declaredClass")); // Returns dijit.form.FilteringSelect
    });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/6RRUK/

Using the `data-dojo-type` will not work because:

1. It's not a widget property, if you would try to achieve this you should be requesting the DOM property itself.
2. The `data-dojo-type` property usually disappears when the markup is being parsed by the Dojo parser.